# Disparar animação com scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tentei incluir a função de Fade nos seguintes elementos, porém não tive sucesso. O *default* que mostrado no site é [este](http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/examples/basic/simple_tweening.html).

Quero aplicar isso a tag `<p>` para quando eu der scroll e passar por elas, elas aumentem a fonte, ou deem *fade-in*. Mas não estou conseguindo entender como funciona

HTML

```
<section data-slide="2" id="acqua"> 
    <h1>Papel Interfolhado<div class="ball"><img class="papel" src="img/papel.png"/></div></h1>
    <div id="descricao">
        <p>O papel toalha Safira tem qualidade <br/>e maciez comprovada.</p>
        <p>O guardanapo de papel Safira <br/>é ultra-absorvente</p>
         <p>É macio e foi feito pensando <br/>na consciência ambiental e na <br/>preservação do meio ambiente</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
   // build tween
   var tween = TweenMax.fromTo("#animate2", 0.5, 
       {"border-top": "0px solid white"},
       {"border-top": "30px solid white", backgroundColor: "blue", scale: 0.7}
     );

   // build scene
   var scene = new ScrollScene({triggerElement: "#trigger2", duration: 300})
           .setTween(tween)
           .addTo(controller);

   // show indicators (requires debug extension)
   scene.addIndicators();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zZEVJ/).

[ScrollMagic no GitHub](https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic).

Comment: Na forma atual, sua pergunta é incompreensível. Tente entender o problema que você está querendo resolver e depois [edit]e sua pergunta para esclarecer melhor qual é sua dúvida. Ajude-nos ajudar você.

Comment: vou tentar, e que ja apaguei o codigo e refiz.. nunca usei o stack.. to meio perdido aqui..

Comment: posta seu código tbm no jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zZEVJ/


quero fazer as letras aparecerem uma apos a outra conforme dou scroll na pagina.. to aprendendo jquery, e so acho tutoriais em ingles, to com uma dificuldade nervosa, acabei de pagar um curso de ingles, hahahaha nao da mais !

Comment: Oi, denis, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Por favor, **[edit]e** sua pergunta sempre que tiver novas informações que acrescentar, e tente caprichar no português porque senão tem que vir um editor e consertar. Talvez não tenha feito o [**Tour**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) ainda, é fácil e explica porque o SOPT é diferente, se puder aproveite também e confira o mini-guia **[ask]**. Boa sorte!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cansei de procurar no seu plugin. Não encontrei nenhuma relação entre o `ScrollMagic` e o `TweenMax` que colocou...

Assim aqui fica uma solução sem o plugin. Vale o que vale...

#### Versão minimalista: http://jsfiddle.net/9qn99fyp/

#### Exemplo com o teucódigo: http://jsfiddle.net/8j5ckd9v/

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    var elementos = $('section div p');
    elementos = elementos.map(function () {
        return {
            el: this,
            pos: $(this).position().top
        };
    });
    $(document).scroll(function () {
        var posicaoScroll = $(document).scrollTop();
        elementos.each(function () {
            if (this.pos < posicaoScroll) $(this.el).animate({'opacity': 1}, 500);
        })
    })
});
```

#### Os passos que dei:

- procurei todos os elementos `p` dentro de `section div`, reorganizei essa array em array de objetos com o elemento e a posição do mesmo na página.
- adicionei o .scroll() do jQuery para disparar o meu código quando o scroll acontece
- a cada scroll vai procurar nos elementos os que têm posição inferior à do scroll (ou seja, já estão visiveis) e faz ele aparecer

Talvez precise de ajustes, mas a sua pergunta não foi muito clara. Se precisar mais ajuda é só comentar...

Answer (score -2):

//Usa esse parâmetro aqui pra que tu possa situar o valor do scroll…
Escreve esse comando no teu código e depois da um console.log com event ‘scroll’.

Const valorDoScroll = document.body.scrollheight + window.innerHeight

Console.log(ValordoScroll)

//A partir daqui tu pode usar isso pra fazer renderizar qualquer tipo de alteração no scroll.

Aí tu pode fazer o seguinte no caso de scrollar pra mudar o tamanho da fonte.

Window.addEventListen(‘scroll’,function(){
//transforma o valor do scroll pra Int

Const ScrollInt = (Window.scrollX/valorDoScroll)*100

//se tudo estiver nos conformes você terá um valor de 0 a 100 relacionado ao tamanho da Window…

Aí tu aplica no elemento

Element.style.fontSize =`${ScrollInt}px`

//pronto! Com isso você vai disparar assim que scrollar…

Se quiser fazer isso em outros momentos específicos é só usar condicionais!

})

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).