# Descobrir posição do Scroll de um determinado objeto

Tags: javascript, jquery, rolamento

É possivel saber a posição do **scroll** de um determinado objeto através de Jquery ou Javascript puro?
tentei `var posobj = $("#meuobjeto_id").scrollTop();`
Porém, o valor obtido está sendo sempre 0.
Alguma ideia?
Eu queria que quando o usuário passa-se por determinado objeto(não clicando, ou passando o mouse, e sim rolando a página) o objeto se anima-se, para isso estou querendo usar o `scrollTop()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Por passos, o que precisa fazer é:

1. saber a posição do elemento que pretende na página para poder comparar com o valor do scroll num dado momento.
2. ter um oscultador de evento que mede a quantidade atual scroll a cada momento do scroll
3. comparar o scroll atual com a posicao inicial do objeto e agir segundo uma condição `if`

Um [exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/sEYs5/1/) que fiz para [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16479/129):

```
var posicaoInicial = $('#meuobjeto_id').position().top;
$(document).scroll(function () { // oscultador de scroll
    var posicaoScroll = $(document).scrollTop(); // obtem a quantidade de scroll no momento
     if (posicaoInicial < posicaoScroll) $('#meuobjeto_id').animate({'opacity': 1}, 500);
})
```

O `if (posicaoInicial < posicaoScroll)` compára os valores e faz correr o `.animate()` quando o scroll for maior que a posição inicial do seu elemento.

Answer (score 3):

Utilize [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) para achar a posição do objeto

```
$("#meuobjeto_id").offset().top
```

E compare o `$(window).scrollTop()` com o valor obtido. Você pode fazer algo tipo

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($("#meuobjeto_id").offset().top > $(window).scrollTop()){
        // animar
    }
});
```