# Como fazer os elementos aparecerem com o scrool do mouse?

Tags: html5, css3, animação

```js
Visibility.onVisible(function(){
 setTimeout(function(){
  $(".animar").addClass("animated fadeInDown"); }, 400);
 setTimeout(function(){
  $(".animar2").addClass("animated fadeInDown"); }, 800);
 setTimeout(function(){
  $(".animar3").addClass("animated fadeInDown"); }, 1200);
 setTimeout(function(){
  $(".animar4").addClass("animated fadeInDown"); }, 1600);
 setTimeout(function(){
  $(".animar5").addClass("animated fadeInDown"); }, 2000);
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.animar,
.animar2,
.animar3,
.animar4,
.animar5 {
  opacity: 0;
}
.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInDown {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeInDown {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}
.fadeInDown {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInDown;
  animation-name: fadeInDown;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/visibility.js/1.2.3/visibility.min.js"></script>



<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-12" style="padding: 150px; background-color: red">
    <p class="animar">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12" style="padding: 150px; background-color: green">
    <p class="animar2">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12" style="padding: 150px; background-color: white">
    <p class="animar3">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12" style="padding: 150px; background-color: yellow">
    <p class="animar4">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12" style="padding: 150px; background-color: orange">
    <p class="animar5">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Este código utiliza uma biblioteca chamada [VisibilityJS](https://github.com/ai/visibilityjs). Toda vez que eu recarregar a página ela faz com que conteúdo apareça de uma transição suave.

Eu quero fazer com que o conteúdo só apareça com o scrool/rolar do mouse.

[Como neste exemplo](https://demo.deliciousthemes.com/stag/homepage-fullscreen-intro/)

Como posso fazer isso?

> Se houver outro plugin que faça isso também aceito. Meu objetivo é aprender a colocar essa animação em qualquer site.

Comment: Acho que é duplicada de http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16479/129

Comment: Não é não. O efeito é diferente ;)

Comment: Podes explicar de que maneira é diferente? Ou seja, qual é a diferença que o outro link não mostra como fazer?

Comment: No outro link, ao acionar o scrool do mouse o conteúdo já está lá e tem seu tamanho expandido. Eu quero que o conteúdo esteja oculto e ao rolar o mouse ele apareça de uma forma suave

Comment: Exatamente assim: https://pages.github.com/

Comment: É assim que queres? http://jsfiddle.net/Lt4ojtyp/

Answer (score 0):

Fala, Zkk! Tudo bem?

Confere se [esse artigo](https://medium.com/@totododoido/ativando-anima%C3%A7%C3%B5es-durante-o-scroll-cd2b95a7a81b#.58b1mwa42) resolve seu problema.

A didática é simples e na minha opinião esse é o método mais fácil de reproduzir esses efeitos. Além de tudo ele explica sobre o viewport, que é parte importante na lógica pra criar isso.

Abraços!